# Integrating absolute terms

Tags: integration, absolute-value

This is just to clarify my doubt regarding absolute values functions.

Lets say there is a function $$f(x) = ax^{2} - \left|\frac{bx}{c}\right|$$

and we are asked to integrate this over $-\infty \to \infty$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx$$

So do we have to first redefine the function like this?
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
ax^{2} - \left(\frac{bx}{c}\right), & x \ge 0 \\
ax^{2} + \left(\frac{bx}{c}\right), & x \lt 0
\end{cases}$$

and then redefine the integral like this?

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{0} ax^{2} + \left(\frac{bx}{c}\right) dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} ax^{2} - \left(\frac{bx}{c}\right) dx$$

and what happens at 0? is this continuous at x = 0

Comment: Sure, with the caveat that the integral will be either $\pm \infty$ according to the sign of $a$ (and with the exact simplification of the absolute value depending on the sign of $b/c$).

Comment: So you mean we can't just omit the sign of $\frac{b}{c}$ and $f(x)$ has to be redefined over four cases? $$x \ge 0  \& \frac{b}{c} \ge 0$$ $$x \ge 0  \& \frac{b}{c} \lt 0$$ $$x \lt 0 \& \frac{b}{c} \ge 0$$  $$x \lt 0  \& \frac{b}{c} \lt 0$$

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But the signs of $b$ and $c$ don't actually affect the integral at all.

Comment: Ah so we can take $\left|\frac{b}{c}\right|$ out and evaluate it later after doing the integral?

Comment: Sure, you can. $ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have the right idea. Notice that
$$f(x)=ax^2-\left| \frac{bx}{c}\right|=ax^2-\left| \frac{b}{c}\right|\cdot |x|$$
And for the time being we will just set $j=\left| \frac{b}{c}\right|$. And what we know is that, now like you said, we have this piece wise function
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
ax^{2} - jx, & x \ge 0 \\
ax^{2} + jx, & x \lt 0
\end{cases}$$
And therefore we have, like you said
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{0} (ax^{2} + jx) dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} (ax^{2} - jx) dx$$
And notice that we have no issues with zero because the whole $jx$ term becomes zero, making the absolute value irrelevant. And yes, this function **is continuous** at $x=0$.
Also note, that since we can break $\left|\frac{bx}{c}\right|$ into $\left|\frac{b}{c}\right|\cdot |x|$, the only thing we have to worry about is $|x|$, which we did handle. This is because $\left|\frac{b}{c}\right|$ only amounts to a constant.

Comment: Yea and then we can evaluate the $j$ term with its sign after we are done with the integration :)